# Unable to determine forest/domain functional level

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain

I already have a domain controller setup on Wind2k8 R2 Standard and am trying to get another system running on Win2k8 R2 Enterprise to also become another domain controller for the same domain.

For the sake of simplifying, I'll call the first Win2k8 as **SERVER-A** and the second Win2k8 Enterprise as **SERVER-B**.

I'm getting the forest or domain functional level incompatibility error as shown:

[image]

I have determined the domain and forest functional level of the **SERVER-A** to be set at **Windows 2008 R2**.

I'm trying to determine the domain and forest functional level of **SERVER-B**, but I can't seem to do. It doesn't even show up. Here's a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Servers don't have functional levels. The OS of the second server isn't compatible with the forest/domain functional levels of your existing domain. Use an OS that is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Domain and Forest Functional Levels, are properties of (respectively) *domains* and *forests*, not of individual servers. Additionally, if your SERVER-B is not yet a domain controller then it cannot report on a functional level.

It looks like your issue is that the domain functional level is Windows Server 2008 R2, which means that all domain controllers must be Windows Server 2008 R2 or later. Your SERVER-B is Windows Server 2008, thus is too old for this domain.

To promote SERVER-B to a domain controller you must first upgrade it to Windows Server 2008 **R2** or later.